# How do I add extra space for the transparent status bar in a navigation drawer?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, material-design

I have a navigation drawer with a header view (using NavigationView) that stretches behind into the status bar, just like Google's. My app supports all the way back to 2.3, so some versions support transparent status bars and some don't.

Let's say my header content height is 72dp. Here's the behavior I want:

- When transparent status bars are supported, make the height of the header 72dp + status bar height. Thus, the header will have the same *effective* height.
- When transparent status bars are NOT support, make the height of the header 72dp.

I realize I could have a `dimens` value with 72dp, and a `dimens-v19` entry with 72dp + 24dp (current status bar height), but I don't like how hacky it is. Plus, if the status bar size changes, it'll have to be updated.

Currently, setting the size to 72dp makes it look proper on Android 4.3 and below, but too small on 4.4 and above. Setting it to 96dp makes it look proper on 4.4 and above but too big on 4.3 and below.

How can I get the status bar insets programmatically?